# Is it possible to add stories to sprint in Jira

Tags: jira

I have stories and multiple tasks for each stories. When creating a new sprint, I'd like to drag and drop stories to the sprint so that all the tasks inside the story get automatically added to the sprint. Is this possible? Currently in the sprint window, I can only view all the tasks and not the stories.

Comment: Which version are using: Jira cloud or Jira Server?

Comment: @AbdulKarim Jira server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because of a filter I had set for the project where I filtered out all stories from the backlog screen. Issue was fixed upon removing this filter.